# Android NDK error in strings.h, possibly due to error in size_t

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm having problems with building X11 for Android using the NDK.  I'm using the latest NDK with droid-wrapper.  I've updated [droid-wrapper](https://github.com/clashthebunny/droid-wrapper/) to work with most of the things I'm building, but it really just adds a bunch of compiler options.  I have it print out what options it's using below.  I've gotten pretty far, but I am running into this problem building some of the libraries:

```
 CC     AuDispose.lo
droid-debug(compile): /opt/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I/home/rmason/androix/usr/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -fno-strict-aliasing -Wbad-function-cast -Wformat=2 -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/home/rmason/androix/usr/include -MT AuDispose.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/AuDispose.Tpo -c AuDispose.c -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/AuDispose.o -I/opt/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -DANDROID -DSK_RELEASE -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb-interwork -fpic -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fmessage-length=0
In file included from /opt/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:42,
             from AuDispose.c:34:
/opt/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/strings.h:47: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
/opt/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/strings.h:47: error:     conflicting types for 'memset'
AuDispose.c: In function 'XauDisposeAuth':
AuDispose.c:44: error: too many arguments to function 'memset'
make[1]: *** [AuDispose.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rmason/androix/lib/libXau'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I look at strings.h and line 47 is this:

```
void     bzero(void *, size_t);
```

I've seen other people having trouble with this type of line because size_t is the wrong value.  Some have fixed it by replacing size_t with the kernel's definition.  My guess is that the order in which I'm including things is clobbering some definition that I really need.

Here's a little background if people like the whole story:

I'm trying to build [Androix](https://github.com/tmzt/androix-xserver) using a slightly modified droid-wrapper].  I made a script (in my github repo as androix-buildscript) to build the whole shebang.  It checks everything out and builds everything.  Right now I'm having the following results:

- Success: util/macros
- Success: proto/xproto
- Success: lib/libxtrans
- Success: xcb/proto
- Success: xcb/pthread-stubs
- Failure: lib/libXau # strings.h error
- Failure: xcb/libxcb # missing Xau
- Success: proto/xextproto
- Success: proto/kbproto
- Success: proto/inputproto
- Failure: lib/libX11 # missing libxcb
- Failure: lib/libxkbfile  # missing X11
- Failure: app/xkbcomp # ./xkbparse.c... configure: error: cannot check for file existence when cross compiling make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
- Success: xkeyboard-config
- Success: mesa/drm
- Success: proto/fixesproto
- Success: proto/damageproto
- Success: proto/xcmiscproto
- Success: proto/bigreqsproto
- Success: proto/compositeproto
- Success: proto/recordproto
- Success: proto/scrnsaverproto
- Success: proto/resourceproto
- Failure: freetype  # still working on figuring out what the best way of building this would be, TODO
- Success: lib/libfontenc
- Failure: lib/libXfont # missing fontsproto, TODO
- Failure: lib/libXdmcp # similar problem to strings.h libXau problem
- Failure: pixman # different looking problem with 'Elf32_auxv_t', but may be the same as the strings.h problem with size_t.  They are both DEFINE oriented problems.

Thanks for taking the time to check this out.  I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finish the make by commenting the lines in strings.h that showed error. Also I used  memset in AuDispose.c instead of bzero.